# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I switched from react native navigation v1 to v2 and I have theses 5 errors when trying to sync my files with Android Studio.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-navigation.

I tried to clear .iml files and .idea folder, invalidate caches and restart.

Configuration:
react-native: 0.51.0,
react-native-navigation: ^2.4.0,
Android Studio: 3.1.1

Android build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal() 
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 19
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}

subprojects { subproject ->
afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative55") || names.contains("reactNative56")  || names.contains("reactNative57")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative51"
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 723
        versionName "1.72"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        versionNameSuffix '3'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-appsflyer')
    compile project(':react-native-text-input-reset')
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-version-check')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-intercom')
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-rate')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    // From node_modules
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    // Firebase dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.6.0'
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.0"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' 
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp;


import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib;
import com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerConversionListener;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    /**
    * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
    * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
    */
    //    @Override
    //    protected String getMainComponentName() {
    //        return "MyApp";
    //    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.myapp;

import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage; 
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost; 
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage; 
// import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage; 
// import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader; 
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication; 
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost; 
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.ReactGateway; 
import com.nikolaiwarner.RNTextInputReset.RNTextInputResetPackage; 
import com.reactlibrary.RNRatePackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestorePackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager; 
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk; 
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage; 
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage; 
import io.xogus.reactnative.versioncheck.RNVersionCheckPackage; 
import com.bugsnag.BugsnagReactNative;

import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage; 
import com.dylanvann.fastimage.FastImageViewPackage; 
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo; 
import com.robinpowered.react.Intercom.IntercomPackage; 
import io.intercom.android.sdk.Intercom;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable; 
import android.app.Activity; 
// import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.ActivityCallbacks; 
// import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication; 
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import com.appsflyer.reactnative.RNAppsFlyerPackage;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {



private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
  return mCallbackManager;
}

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

  @Override
protected ReactGateway createReactGateway() {
    ReactNativeHost host = new NavigationReactNativeHost(this, isDebug(), createAdditionalReactPackages()) {
        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
    };
    return new ReactGateway(this, isDebug(), host);
}

  @Override
  public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          // new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNAppsFlyerPackage(MainApplication.this),
          new RNTextInputResetPackage(),
          BugsnagReactNative.getPackage(),
          new RNVersionCheckPackage(),
          new ReactVideoPackage(),
          new IntercomPackage(),
          new FastImageViewPackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo(),
          new RNRatePackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(), 
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
          new LinearGradientPackage(),
    );
  }

  @Override
  protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
  }
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
  return mReactNativeHost;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  Intercom.initialize(this, "android_sdk-mykey", "mykey");
  BugsnagReactNative.start(this);


  setActivityCallbacks(new ActivityCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
  });

  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
  SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}


@Override
public boolean isDebug() {
  return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new RNTextInputResetPackage(),
          // new MainReactPackage(),
          BugsnagReactNative.getPackage(),
          new RNVersionCheckPackage(),
          new RNRatePackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseAuthPackage(),
          new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage(),
          new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage(),
          new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
          // new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
          new RNDeviceInfo(),
          new ReactVideoPackage(),
          new IntercomPackage(),
          new FastImageViewPackage(),
          new MapsPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
          new LinearGradientPackage(),
          new RNAppsFlyerPackage(MainApplication.this)
  );
}}
```

My settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android')
```

And gradle-wraper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Sorry for the long code but I maybe made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Have you manually changed the `react-native-navigation` version in `package.json`? If so, did you run `npm install` after doing so?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the RNN module is not present.

Quick checklist to resolve this:

1) Check `package.json`, it should contain in its dependencies `"react-native-navigation": "^2.11.0",` or another similar version. If it does not, the module will need to be (re-)installed. Use `npm install --save react-native-navigation`, or yarn equivalent.

2) Check inside the directory `./node_modules/react-native-navigation`. If it only contains `'lib/android/app/<single file>'`, your module may have been deleted. If so, `npm install` / `yarn install` should recover it.