# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-snackbar

Tags: android, react-native

Facing mentioned error in case of below two packages every time I install a new package,

```
react-native-snackbar
react-native-local-auth
```

when I refer to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973768/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv), One of the solutions is occurring in my case,

> 2) Check inside the directory ./node_modules/react-native-navigation. If it only contains 'lib/android/app/', your module may have been deleted. If so, npm install / yarn install should recover it.

once I do `npm install` everything will be alright.

Can anybody let me know why it is happening and especially for the above mentioned packages? And what would be the resolution for this?

Comment: Have you linked library using 'react-native link react-native-snackbar'?

Comment: @Cool7 Yes, I have done so.